# Exclude a specific char in a regex

Tags: php, regex, url

The following regex works perfectly when I need to detect an URL.

```
`((?:https?|ftp)://\S+?)(?=[]).,;:!?]?(?:\s|\Z)|\Z)`
```

But I also have a regex which detects the [url=...]...[/url] code, and in this case, the texts becomes : ..., and as the http://... is still present, the URL is detected a second time by the quoted regex.

I would like to prevent the URLs starting with the equal sign from being detected by the previous regex :
http://... would be detected, but not =http://

I tried

```
`(^\=)((?:https?|ftp)://\S+?)(?=[]).,;:!?]?(?:\s|\Z)|\Z)`
```

But it doesn't work.

Thanks by advance ! :)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

think the following would work using a negative lookbehind `(?<!)`

```
(?<!=)((?:https?|ftp)://\S+?)(?=[]).,;:!?]?(?:\s|\Z)|\Z)
```